# Schedule task error when running a VS 2010 project that uses NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a VS 2010 project from which I generated an exe and set up a scheduled task. But whenever the task runs I get an error in the NHibernate.cs file saying Current Session is null

```
public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
}
```

How do I overcome this? Is this something I need to verify programmatically whether a session exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something I need to verify programmatically whether a session exists or not?

Yes, if you want to use the current session mechanism to control the lifetime of a session across multiple application blocks, you need to open and bind a session to the `CurrentSessionContext` yourself.

In addition, you need to specify which kind of `CurrentSessionContext` you want to use, NHibernate provides different default implementations for e.g. web scenarios or console like applications. The reason for it is that the session will be bound to different kind of state instances.

In web scenarios, the implementation uses `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items`. This makes sure the session survives one http request.

In console applications and also in your scenario you would use `ThreadStatic` session context. This one ensures that per thread you have one session.

To bind a session to the `CurrentSessionContext` you have to open and bind it (the session factory must be constructed first/once of course.

```
var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
```

From now on `sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();` will return you that session.

You should also close and dispose the session whenever your scope ends, e.g. your thread dies or the request ends (in web apps).

You can configure nhibernate to use a certain context. Using Fluently configuration it looks like this:

```
 Fluently.Configure()
    ....
    .CurrentSessionContext("thread_static")
```

Answer (score 1):

The set of provided information *(including the code snippet)* are simply not enough to say - what exactly is wrong. Regardless of this fact, there is one very common suspected:

- web implementation used in a console app *(without the `System.Web` infrastructure runtime in place)*

Check your setting and implementation of the *current session persistence (Http.Context, Thread...)*. To get more understanding, please, start with the documentation:

[2.3. Contextual Sessions](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session)

An extract:

> Most applications using NHibernate need some form of "contextual" sessions, where a given session is in effect throughout the scope of a given context. However, across applications the definition of what constitutes a context is typically different; and different contexts define different scopes to the notion of current.
>
> Starting with version 1.2, NHibernate added the `ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` method. The processing behind `ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` is pluggable. An extension interface (`NHibernate.Context.ICurrentSessionContext`) and a new configuration parameter (`hibernate.current_session_context_class`) have been added to allow pluggability of the scope and context of defining current sessions.

An example in the documentation shows the custom implementation of the *session persistence in a web environment* - [Chapter 1. Quickstart with IIS and Microsoft SQL Server](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats)

```
public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    ISession currentSession = context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] as ISession;

    if (currentSession == null)
    {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] = currentSession;
    }

    return currentSession;
}
```

I.e. in console application *(representing single operation)* we can place session in some program instance property...and use it during the execution.